# While using OneToMany tags .. No Persistence provider for EntityManager - Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Well i've benn looking for this problem wasting so much time, so i'm here.

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "secretario")
public class Secretario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long codigoS;
    @Column
    private String nombre;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigoE")
    private Empleado e;
```

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Entity
@Table
public class Empleado implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1l;
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    private long codigoE;
    @Column
    private String apellido;
    @Column
    private String nombre;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "e")
    private ArrayList<Secretario> secretario;
```

When i use te OneToMany and ManyToOne tags i got this exception and i dont why... or how ...

```java
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Persistencia
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at tests.TestEmpleados.main(TestEmpleados.java:22)
```

here is my persistence config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">


    <persistence-unit name="Persistencia">
        <!-- <description>
             Persistence unit for the JPA tutorial of the Hibernate Getting Started Guide
         </description>-->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- Representar clases -->
        <class>model.Empleado</class>
        <class>model.Secretario</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And my maven config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Some way i fixed using the @Transient tag and my entities were correctly persisted, but when i tried to query them i got a null in the OneToMany relation bcz it tells hibernate not to do something with that attribute...

```java
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistencia");
        manager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

This is where the exception shows

@UPDATE

Somehow i figured out that @OneToMany only accepts Collection Type as List,set, Map, etc but not "ArrayList" and i just changed the data type and it work fine..

Comment: please post complete stack trace, looks like issue with persistence xml.

Answer (score 0):

@Transient - tells hibernate not persist such fields, that's why you have null at this fields. Also that's why you don't get problem again.

@ManyToOne are Lazy by default, so you should get them inside transaction.

You can achive this to annotate method where you use this property with @Transactional if you use JPA. Or you can use methods beginTransaction(), endTransaction() from EntityManager.
As long as your entity will go from transactional scope error will occure again. So convert your entity to dto before gone from transactional scope.

Another solution you can annotate your fields as Eager, so they will be downloaded from database with parent entity.

But Eager - bad solution, don't use it if don't know what is it.

Comment: It seems to be a tag problem more than a Lazy getter from the relation, bcz it only happens when i use it explicitly :(

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the question but certain things depends on your setup i.e using as Java SE or J2EE application.

For Java SE, make sure you have your persistence file inside `META-INF/persistence.xml` under resources folder, Please check this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persistence-xml/) or in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm)

For J2EE application, you generally configure the JNDI name in your server's configuration and then use that JNDI name inside your persistence.xml.

Also, please check all your database credentials and check access to it manually and follow the stack trace, it will tell you complete story what is going wrong.